# Understanding how to read the iOS Documentation and API Reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, documentation

Take for example an **NSArray**. If we look in the class reference and look in the *Initializing an Array* subsection, we see this method:

```
-(instancetype)initWithObjects:(id)firstObj
```

So since we're creating NSArrays, I want to create an object of an NSArray class and have a pointer of array.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray new];
```

We're going to call the method of `initWithObjects:(id)firstObj`

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"hello", @"world"]];
```

I'm a bit confused on what I can pass in. Take for example the below method:

`-(void)commentOnMediaItem:(Media *)mediaItem withCommentText:(NSString *)commentText;`

I see that I need to pass in a mediaItem and an NSString but when would it be appropriate to subclass and create my own?

I guess my confusion lies in the fact that I only have access to the header file and the public facing methods without truly understanding the implementation of certain methods.

Ultimately, any tips on how to break down the reference guides/documentation and any epiphany providing tips would be graciously appreciated.

Comment: Your `initWithObjects` example is missing some brackets: `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"hello", @"world"]]`: we send `NSArray` class the message to allocate a new instance, then we send that instance a message to fill itself up with objects. Both messages need to be enclosed in `[...]`. Knowing Swift would help you with ObjC learning, but learning it simultaneously would just hurt. As a beginner, it would be good to start with a textbook/tutorial, not a reference; those are for when you know what you want, more or less. But this is an opinion question, not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: In fact, what classes to create, which methods they should implement is something even seasoned programmers have problems with, and only experience can tell you how to architect your program. Rite Moar Codez (tm).

Comment: Does this mean that obj-c is your first programming language? If you're trying to learn object-oriented programming for the first time, I'd actually recommend Java or Python. You can get rolling with a lot less "boilerplate" (i.e. all those "files" you have to make to run an iOS app), and it'll make adapting to objective-c a lot easier when the time comes. That said, you seem pretty deep into it already, and if you really want to build an iOS app now, there's a lot of good advice here.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the mis-concept you have written as your understanding.

> Which means that the instance type has been replaced by [NSArray alloc]

No, absolutely no. To explain this we will go through the method/message syntax of Objective-C. If you grasp the method syntax, you can read the documentation easily. For now don't bother about why I wrote *message* with method. It will be clear by end of post.

```
-(instancetype)initWithObjects:(id)firstObj
```

`instancetype` - return data type of method. This means the return type is same as that of receiver.
`initWithObjects:` - method signature.
`id` - data type of method argument. `id` means it can be of any data type which is an object
`firstObj` - method argument

Now let's see what does `[NSArray alloc]` does. This means an object of `NSArray` has been created and allocated memory for it, but it is not yet initialised.

**Message** - Objective-C uses message passing as a means to call methods. A message is sent to receiver, which is basically the object who will be having the associated method implementation.
So when a message of `initWithObjects:` is sent to a raw object of `NSArray`, this means `NSArray` class will be having the implementation of this method and once finished it will return an object of `NSArray`

Message passing is bit tricky to understand for a beginner, if it is not clear now then I suggest you get a good grasp of language and then try to understand it. But do read the full section of [Working with Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW2) to have the clear picture.

> Is learning Swift concurrently going to help?

Totally opinion based as @Amadan already mentioned. I personally feel that it will mess up with your mind. Learn one language first then learn the difference.